# How do I get the current action from within a controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How do I get the current action from within a controller? `current_page?` works for views, but not controllers.

```
redirect_to step3_users_path unless current_page?(step3_users_path)
```

I also tried

```
controller.action_name == 'step3'
```

I also tried

```
params[:action_name] == 'step3'
```

Comment: action_name gives you the current action name

Comment: @Joel `#action_name` is not even a method in Rails. http://api.rubyonrails.org/

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Controllers have `action_name` method/accessor (defined in `AbstractController::Base` for current rails, `ActionController::Base` for older)

Comment: For edge rails defined here: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb#L21

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html expicitly states to use `action_name` instead of `params[:action]`

Comment: Note that the correct usage is not `controller.action_name` but just plain `action_name` from within controller code.

Comment: Strange, it's not in the docs. I tried searching for that. http://api.rubyonrails.org

Comment: You can use `action_name` in a ViewComponent also.

Answer (score 4):

you can use `__method__` to get to the name of the current method.

e.g

```
 def Klass
   def method1
     puts __method__
   end
 end

 > k = Klass.new
 > k.method1
 => :method1
```

Once the request goes through Rails, you will be able to access this in the Controller:

```
params[:controller]
params[:action]
```

In a view, you can access `action_name`

Comment: It's in a `before_filter`. I don't want the current method.

Comment: I added to my answer

Answer (score 1):

This worked.

```
logger.debug params
redirect_to step3_users_path unless params[:action] == 'step3'
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to get started is to set a breakpoint somewhere within your code where your action is running.

If you are using `pry`, do so with `binding.pry`, then you can list all params that are being passed by that action by writing `params` into the console and pressing enter.

Once you get the name of the param, then get it by using, for example `params[:action]`, to get the name of the controller action.